# minimum delay for mpeg-dash stream using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, mp4box

I am trying to stream my video files using MP4Box and ffmpeg and using mpeg-dash, I transcoded my video using this command for *video*:

```
ffmpeg -i main720.MTS -movflags faststart -vcodec libx264 -r 24 -tune zerolatency -tune fastdecode -bf 0 -slices 0 -x264opts intra_refresh=1 -g 96 -b:v 700k -maxrate 700k -bufsize 400k -an -s 640*360 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:02:00 main720_700_video.mp4
```

and this for *audio*:

```
ffmpeg -i main720.MTS -movflags faststart -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -vn -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:02:00 main720_700_audio.mp4
```

and this to make the *mpeg-dash* file:

```
MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -profile onDamand -rap -segment-name %s_ -out manifest.mpd main720_300_video.mp4 main720_700_video.mp4 main720_300_audio.mp4
```

but I am NOT getting a fast stream and it has got some delay, any suggestions on how to make this delay lower??

Comment: What do you mean by "a fast stream"? And what "delay" do you want to make lower?

Comment: right now I have a 3 sec delay for play back. when I seek in the video it gets 3 secs to start playing @szatmary